# Why is the Descriptor not getting called when defined as instance attribute?

Tags: python, descriptor

When I make the "data" variable a class variable, the following works, but when I make it an object variable, the descriptor is not called. Please help.

```
class Data(object):
    products = {
        'milk': {'price': 1.50, 'quantity': 10},
        'eggs': {'price': 0.20, 'quantity': 100},
        'cheese': {'price': 2.00, 'quantity': 10}
    }
    def __get__(self, obj, klas):
        print "Here in descriptor"
        return self.products

class BusinessLogic(object):
    def __init__(self):         # When I remove these 2 lines 
        self.data = Data()
    #data = Data()             # and enable this line it does work !

def main():
    b = BusinessLogic()
    b.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because descriptors should only be defined as class attributes, not instance attributes:

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

> The following methods only apply when an instance of the class
>   containing the method (a so-called descriptor class) appears in an
>   owner class (**the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class
>   dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents**).

To make descriptor work with instance attributes as well you need to override the `__getattribute__` method of `BusinessLogic`.(Haven't tested this thoroughly, but works fine for your case):

```
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if hasattr(obj, '__get__'):
            return obj.__get__(self, type(self))
        return obj
```

In case you've a data descriptor then you need to handle the `__setattr__` part as well.

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
    try:
        obj = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        # This will be raised if we are setting the attribute for the first time
        # i.e inside `__init__` in your case.
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
    else:
        if hasattr(obj, '__set__'):
            obj.__set__(self, val)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for this answer, it really helped me out.